# android broadcast receiver (call and sms received) not working in android nougat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

android call and SMS broadcast receiver working perfectly till marshmallow 6.0, but in android nougat , it is not working when app is closed, and when app is in background, then its working fine in android nougat(N). please can anyone help me for this issue.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        Log.d("t savedNumber", savedNumber);
        return;
    }else{
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

        Log.d("t incoming Number", number+" state: "+state+ " stateStr: "+stateStr);

        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
 }
}
```

**permisssion added in mainfest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**registering receiver**

```
     <receiver android:name=".Receiver.CallReceiver ">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action    android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: also i added this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />

Comment: runTime permission is missing

Comment: @Eazyz i have already given the runtime permission

Comment: @DhananjayGupta in android 7.0 reciever will not work so how would you solve this problem in the latest version. Please help me i am also stuck here

Answer (score 3):

Try this service ..!

SMS Observer

```
 package com.demo.service;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {

    String TAG =SmsObserver.class.getSimpleName();

    static final Uri SMS_STATUS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    private Context mContext;
    private String contactId = "", contactName = "";
    private String smsBodyStr = "", phoneNoStr = "";
    private long smsDatTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public SmsObserver(Handler handler, Context ctx) {
        super(handler);
        mContext = ctx;
    }

    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        try {
            Log.e("Info", "Notification on SMS observer");
            Cursor sms_sent_cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(SMS_STATUS_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (sms_sent_cursor != null) {
                if (sms_sent_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String protocol = sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
                    Log.e("Info", "protocol : " + protocol);
                    //for send  protocol is null
                    if (protocol == null) {
                        /*
                        String[] colNames = sms_sent_cursor.getColumnNames();
                        if(colNames != null){
                            for(int k=0; k<colNames.length; k++){
                                Log.e("Info","colNames["+k+"] : " + colNames[k]);
                            }
                        }
                        */
                        int type = sms_sent_cursor.getInt(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
                        Log.e("Info", "SMS Type : " + type);
                        // for actual state type=2
                        if (type == 2) {
                            Log.e("Info", "Id : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Thread Id : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("thread_id")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Address : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Person : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("person")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Date : " + sms_sent_cursor.getLong(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Read : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("read")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Status : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("status")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Type : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("type")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Rep Path Present : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("reply_path_present")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Subject : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("subject")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Body : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));
                            Log.e("Info", "Err Code : " + sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("error_code")));

                            smsBodyStr = sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("body")).trim();
                            phoneNoStr = sms_sent_cursor.getString(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("address")).trim();
                            smsDatTime = sms_sent_cursor.getLong(sms_sent_cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));

                            Log.e("Info", "SMS Content : " + smsBodyStr);
                            Log.e("Info", "SMS Phone No : " + phoneNoStr);
                            Log.e("Info", "SMS Time : " + smsDatTime);

                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
                Log.e("Info", "Send Cursor is Empty");
        } catch (Exception sggh) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error on onChange : " + sggh.toString());
        }
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }//fn onChange


}//End of class SmsObserver
```

Phone State service

```
package com.demo.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class PhoneStateService extends Service {

    String TAG = PhoneStateService.class.getSimpleName();

    boolean isMissedCall = false;
    boolean isRingingCall = false;
    boolean isRingingCallOne = false;

    String onOff;
    String callerID;
    String callerIDOne;
    String[] cIds;
    String[] cIdsOne;

    private CallStateListener mCallStateListener = new CallStateListener();
    private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
    private int mCallState;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mCallState = mTelephonyManager.getCallState();
        mTelephonyManager.listen(mCallStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("onDestroy", "onDestroy");
        mTelephonyManager.listen(mCallStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null; //-- not a bound service--
    }

    private final class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            String getSimSerialNumber = mTelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
            String mPhoneNumber = mTelephonyManager.getLine1Number();


            Log.d("number", "getSimSerialNumber : " + getSimSerialNumber);
            Log.d("number", "mPhoneNumber : " + mPhoneNumber);

            Log.d("number", "number : " + incomingNumber+" callstatelistner : "+state + "  "+Consts.number);

            onOff = SharedPreferenceUtil.getString("onOff","");

            callerID = SharedPreferenceUtil.getString("callerID","");

            callerIDOne = SharedPreferenceUtil.getString("callerIDOne","");

            cIds = new String[0];

            cIdsOne = new String[0];
            Log.d(TAG,"callerID : "+ callerID);
            Log.d(TAG,"callerIDOne : "+ callerIDOne);
            if (!callerID.equals("")) {
                try {
                    callerID = callerID.substring(0, callerID.length() - 1);
                    cIds = callerID.split(",");
                    Log.d(TAG,"callerID  :: "+ cIds.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG,"callerID  :: "+ cIds.length);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (!callerIDOne.equals("")) {
                try {
                    callerIDOne = callerIDOne.substring(0, callerIDOne.length() - 1);
                    cIdsOne = callerIDOne.split(",");

                    Log.d(TAG,"callerIDOne  :: "+ cIdsOne.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG,"callerIDOne  :: "+ cIdsOne.length);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            int OFFHOOK = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            int IDLE = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            int RINGING = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;

// my change
            mCallState = state;
//            Log.v("state","-- "+state+  "  --- "+TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE+" - "+TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK+"  - "+TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING);
            Log.v("state","-- "+state+  "  --- "+IDLE+" - "+OFFHOOK+"  - "+RINGING);
            if (state == 0){
                Log.d(TAG, "state ....0");
                if (state == OFFHOOK) {
                    Log.d("state", "idle --> off hook = new outgoing call"+ Consts.number);
                    // idle --> off hook = new outgoing call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.OUTGOING);

                    callStateOffhoof(incomingNumber);
                } else if (state == RINGING) {
                    Log.d("state", "idle --> ringing = new incoming call"+Consts.number);
                    // idle --> ringing = new incoming call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.INCOMING);
                    callStateRinging(incomingNumber);
                }else if (state == IDLE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "state ....IDLE");
                    Log.d("state", "ringing --> idle = missed call"+Consts.number);
                    // ringing --> idle = missed call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.MISSED);
                    callStateIdeal(incomingNumber);
                }
            }else if (state == 1){
                Log.d(TAG, "state ....1");
                if (state == OFFHOOK) {
                    Log.d("state", "ringing --> off hook = received"+Consts.number);
                    // ringing --> off hook = received
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.RECEIVED);
                    callStateOffhoof(incomingNumber);
                } else if (state == IDLE) {
                    Log.d("state", "ringing --> idle = missed call"+Consts.number);
                    // ringing --> idle = missed call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.MISSED);
                    callStateIdeal(incomingNumber);
                }else if (state == RINGING)  {
                    Log.d("state", "idle --> ringing = new incoming call"+Consts.number);
                    // idle --> ringing = new incoming call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.INCOMING);
                    callStateRinging(incomingNumber);
                }
            }else if (state == 2){
                Log.d(TAG, "state ....2");
                if (state == IDLE) {
                    Log.d("state", "off hook --> idle  = disconnected"+Consts.number);
                    // off hook --> idle  = disconnected
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.ENDED);
                    callStateIdeal(incomingNumber);
                } else if (state == RINGING) {
                    Log.d("state", "off hook --> ringing = another call waiting"+Consts.number);
                    // off hook --> ringing = another call waiting
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.WAITING);
                    callStateRinging(incomingNumber);
                }else if(state==OFFHOOK)
                {
                    String nm = Consts.number;
                    if (!nm.isEmpty()){
                        callStateOffhoof(nm);
                    }else {
                        callStateOffhoof(incomingNumber);
                    }

                }
                Log.d("CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", String.valueOf(state));
            }
            /*switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    if (state == OFFHOOK) {
                        Log.d("state", "idle --> off hook = new outgoing call"+ Consts.number);
                        // idle --> off hook = new outgoing call
                        //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.OUTGOING);

                        callStateOffhoof(incomingNumber);
                    } else if (state == RINGING) {
                        Log.d("state", "idle --> ringing = new incoming call"+Consts.number);
                        // idle --> ringing = new incoming call
                        //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.INCOMING);
                        callStateRinging(incomingNumber);
                    }

                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (state == IDLE) {
                        Log.d("state", "off hook --> idle  = disconnected"+Consts.number);
                        // off hook --> idle  = disconnected
                        //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.ENDED);
                        callStateIdeal(incomingNumber);
                    } else if (state == RINGING) {
                        Log.d("state", "off hook --> ringing = another call waiting"+Consts.number);
                        // off hook --> ringing = another call waiting
                        //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.WAITING);
                        callStateRinging(incomingNumber);
                    }
                    else if(state==OFFHOOK)
                    {
                        String nm = Consts.number;
                        if (!nm.isEmpty()){
                            callStateOffhoof(nm);
                        }else {
                            callStateOffhoof(incomingNumber);
                        }

                    }
                    Log.d("CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", String.valueOf(state));
                    break;

                case 1:
                    if (state == OFFHOOK) {
                        Log.d("state", "ringing --> off hook = received"+Consts.number);
                        // ringing --> off hook = received
                        //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.RECEIVED);
                        callStateOffhoof(incomingNumber);
                    } else if (state == IDLE) {
                        Log.d("state", "ringing --> idle = missed call"+Consts.number);
                        // ringing --> idle = missed call
                        //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.MISSED);
                        callStateIdeal(incomingNumber);
                    }
                    break;
            }*/
            Log.d(TAG, "Outer state.....");
//            mCallState = state; change
        }
    }

    public static void init(Context c) {
        c.startService(new Intent(c, PhoneStateService.class));
        Log.d("Service enabled","Service enabled: " + true);
    }
    boolean b;
    public void callStateRinging(String incomingNumber){
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Is Riging",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        isMissedCall = true;
        isRingingCall = true;
        isRingingCallOne = true;

        Log.d(TAG,"Rebound : "+ onOff);
        if (onOff.equals("on")){

            b = false;
            for (int i=0; i<cIds.length; i++) {
                if (cIds[i].equals(incomingNumber)){
                    b = true;
                }else if (incomingNumber.contains(cIds[i])){
                    b = true;
                }
            }
            if (!b){
                for (int i=0; i<cIdsOne.length; i++) {
                    if (cIdsOne[i].equals(incomingNumber)){
                        b = true;
                    }else if (incomingNumber.contains(cIdsOne[i])){
                        b = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"b : "+b);
            if (!b) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Rebound : disconnectCall");
                disconnectCall();
            }else {
                Log.d(TAG,"Rebound : not disconnectCall because it allow contact...");
            }
        }else if (onOff.equals("off")){
            Log.d(TAG,"Rebound Off");
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateRinging Rebound outer : "+ onOff);
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateRinging Rebound cIds  : "+ cIds.length);
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateRinging Rebound callerID: "+ callerID);
        Log.d("number", "callStateRinging number : " + incomingNumber);
    }

    public void callStateIdeal(String incomingNumber){
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "phone is neither ringing nor in a call",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

        if (!isRingingCall){
                        if (isRingingCallOne) {
                            Intent service;
//                            service = new Intent(this, WaitingMessageService.class);
//                            startService(service);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Servic called");
//                            new Handler().postDelayed(stopWaitnigPopUp, 10000);
                        }
            Log.d(TAG,"Rebound in A call : "+ onOff);
            if (Consts.isInternet()) {
//                            if (onOff.equals("on")) {

                String nm = Consts.number;
                String onlyDigitNum = Consts.getOnlyDigits(nm);
                String onlyDigitNumOne = Consts.getOnlyDigits(incomingNumber);
                Log.d(TAG,"nm : "+ nm);
                Log.d(TAG,"incomingNumber : "+ incomingNumber);
                Log.d(TAG,"onlyDigitNum : "+ onlyDigitNum);
                Log.d(TAG,"onlyDigitNumOne : "+ onlyDigitNumOne);

//                            }
            }else {
                Log.d(TAG,"No Internet so not send any rebounds");
            }
        }

        if (isMissedCall){
            Log.d(TAG,"Rebound : "+ onOff);

            if (Consts.isInternet()) {
                if (onOff.equals("on")) {
                    isMissedCall = false;

                }
            }else {
                Log.d(TAG,"No Internet so not send any rebounds");
            }

                        /*int count = dbHelper.numberOfRows();
                        Log.d(TAG,"count :" + count);
                        if (count != 0){
                            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllData();
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                                    String alive = cursor.getString(1);
                                    String cantactno = cursor.getString(2);
                                    String multimidiyatype = cursor.getString(3);
                                    String path = cursor.getString(4);
                                    String credate = cursor.getString(5);
                                    String message = cursor.getString(6);

                                    if (cantactno.equals(incomingNumber)){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message "+ message + " path :"+ path +" Contact NO;"+ cantactno,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    Log.d(TAG,"--"+incomingNumber + cantactno + path + message);

                                    cursor.moveToNext();
                                }
                            }
                        }*/
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateIdeal Rebound outer : "+ onOff);
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateIdeal Rebound cIds  : "+ cIds.length);
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateIdeal Rebound callerID: "+ callerID);
        Log.d("number", "callStateIdeal number : " + incomingNumber);
    }

    public void callStateOffhoof(String incomingNumber){
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Currently in A call",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        isMissedCall = false;
        isRingingCall = false;
        isRingingCallOne = true;

        if (!isRingingCall){
                        Intent service;
//                        service = new Intent(this,WaitingMessageService.class);
//                        startService(service);
                        Log.d(TAG,"Servic called");
//                        new Handler().postDelayed(stopWaitnigPopUp, 10000);

            Log.d(TAG,"Rebound in A call : "+ onOff);
            if (Consts.isInternet()) {
//                            if (onOff.equals("on")) {

                String nm = Consts.number;
                String onlyDigitNum = Consts.getOnlyDigits(nm);
                String onlyDigitNumOne = Consts.getOnlyDigits(incomingNumber);
                Log.d(TAG,"nm : "+ nm);
                Log.d(TAG,"incomingNumber : "+ incomingNumber);
                Log.d(TAG,"onlyDigitNum : "+ onlyDigitNum);
                Log.d(TAG,"onlyDigitNumOne : "+ onlyDigitNumOne);

//                            }
            }else {
                Log.d(TAG,"No Internet so not send any rebounds");
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateOffhoof Rebound outer : "+ onOff);
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateOffhoof Rebound cIds  : "+ cIds.length);
        Log.d(TAG,"callStateOffhoof Rebound callerID: "+ callerID);
        Log.d("number", "callStateOffhoof number : " + incomingNumber);
    }

    public void disconnectCall(){
        try {
            String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
            String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
            String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
            Method telephonyEndCall;
            Object telephonyObject;
            Object serviceManagerObject;
            telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
            telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
            serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
            serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
            Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                    serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
            Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
            tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
            serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
            IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
            Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            /*Log.error(DialerActivity.this,
                    "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
            Log.error(DialerActivity.this, "Exception object: " + e);*/
        }
    }


}
```

i hope its work for you ..!

Comment: thanks for replay, but when app is killed from recent apps, then not working broadcast receiver in android 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think your forgot to ask for run time permission

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app

Add runtime permission using below code for READ_SMS:

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    String[] permission_list = new String[1];
    permission_list[0] = permission;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
}
```

And than handle result like this:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             // perform your action here

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Add this permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. but i added the runtime permission

Comment: @DhananjayGupta but you forgot to add this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>` to read sms  **you have permission to recieve sms but not for read sms**

Comment: also i added for sms received and read sms permission, but my question is for call receiving. its works when app is in background, but while app is closed, then not working the call and sms broadcast receiver.