# READ_SMS broadcast receiver does not trigger on Noughat and Marshmallow

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I have read several questions in stackoverflow including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900555/android-sms-broadcast-listener-not-working), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994470/android-broadcast-receiver-call-and-sms-received-not-working-in-android-nougat) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019987/sms-broadcast-receiver-not-working), but they did not help me to fix my problem.

I have described my broadcast receiver in android manifest to receive incoming SMSs, but it does not work on version 6.0(Marshmallow) and 7.0(Noughat) altought it works in lower versions like 4.0.

My application have permission to read and receive SMS both in **manifest** and by **granting permissions in run-time** however onReceive off my Broacast receiver is never fired. I also tried to set priority to `MAX_INT`(i.e. 2147483647) but it did not help.

Here is my brodcast receiver description in manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.package.receiver.IncomingSms"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.READ_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the comment on the answer below, but the `permission` attribute you have in your snippet is incorrect. That attribute specifies the permission the _broadcast sender_ must hold. If you include one there at all, it needs to be the `BROADCAST_SMS` one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code which is working fine in marshmallow as well as nougat

Mainifest code :

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".utlis.SMSReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Reciver class code :

```
 public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(".............................123........................");
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ");
}
```

Permission needed:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: BROADCAST_SMS permission is not related to this context.

Comment: This code is working fine for receive incomming msg give this code a try